# Azure KeyVault is giving a null reference exception when running GetSecret()

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

When I try to get the API secret from Azure KeyVault, I am receiving a null reference error. I have the Key set up in the KeyVault, but secret is coming back as `null`.

```
    public static string GetKeyInformation(API_KEY)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(API_KEY))
        {
            var keyVaultUrl = "https://socialflutter.vault.azure.net/";

            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);

            KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret();

            Console.WriteLine($"{secret.Name}: {secret.Value}");

            API_KEY = secret.Value;
        }

        return API_KEY;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null reference error is happening because of the following line:

```
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret();
```

Even if you just have a single secret defined, Azure KeyVault will not know how to read the Key.

You will want the following syntax:

```
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(<KEY_NAME>);
```

To find the `<KEY_NAME>`, refer to the screenshot below:

1. Go to Key Vault
2. Click on Secrets
3. Copy the Name of the Secret

[image: Azure KeyVault]